# Changing the default compiler in visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have the Visual Studio 2010 installed in my system. However, my company has a different central build system and uses the compiler from Visual Studio 6. Is it possible for me to use this compiler for compiling my C++ projects in Visual Studio 2010? If yes, where to configure this? 
I checked in the project settings dialog, but couldn't find any option for this. I know how to use the old compiler from the command line and I don't want to do that.

Comment: Obligatory remark that your company should consider upgrading the compiler at least once every 10-15 years. VC6 is the equivalent of Ford Model T.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Daffodil for Visual Studio extension (http://daffodil.codeplex.com) allows you to set any installed toolset/compiler under Project settings in VS 2010.