# How to change compiler in Visual C++ 2010 Express

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, compiler-construction, mingw

I have Visual C++ 2010 Express and I want to build a 64-bit app.

On OS X we use gcc.

If I install MinGW, how does one change the default compiler in Visual C++ 2010 Express to use MinGW or something else even.

Comment: You don't. Visual C++ is for using the Microsoft compiler. If you want to use a different one, use a different IDE. The Express version doesn't do 64-bit, AFAIK. If you want to use VC++ for this, you have to upgrade to Professional or higher (and pay for it).

Comment: have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11518557/changing-the-default-compiler-in-visual-studio-2010 ?

Comment: VS 2012 express has both 32 and 64 bit compilers.

Comment: You can use makefile projects to use any compiler you want in VC++ Express. You'll get VC++'s editing and code navigation capabilities, but unfortunately you won't get the VC++ debugging capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

you can't easily use a different C++ compiler from Visual C++ Express. but you can just use Visual C++ to build 64-bit app for Windows.

Comment: I don't think it's possible at all in express editions to use a non ms compiler.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: you are probably right (for the in practice). however, there's lots of undocumented functionality in the express editions (e.g. you can fix the color scheme and menu uppercasing of VS 2012 express editions, in much the same way as for the full edition), so i would not say categorically that the only way would be the impractical emulation of [cl.exe]

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to use something with MinGW, you could try using Notepad++ for editing code and compile with MinGW.

Visual Studio is pretty much restricted to its proprietary compiler and linker. If you are worried about keeping your code portable the follow ANSI/ISO C++ standards. Even then you will most likely have to recompile on each platform.

You could also check out the Code::Blocks IDE http://www.codeblocks.org/ it's configurable with MinGW.

Comment: Yes I did, thank you! It's nice to see a maintained version of Dev-C++ floating around.

Comment: I don't understand why you accepted this answer. It doesn't even attempt to answer the question that you asked.